# Trouble mocking `Resolv::DNS.open`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, mocking, minitest

I'm trying to mock the code below using MiniTest/Mocks. But I keep getting this error when running my test.

```
Minitest::Assertion: unexpected invocation: #<Mock:0x7fa76b53d5d0>.size()
unsatisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, not yet invoked: #<Mock:0x7fa76b53d5d0>.getresources("_F5DC2A7B3840CF8DD20E021B6C4E5FE0.corwin.co", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME)
satisfied expectations:
- expected exactly once, invoked once: Resolv::DNS.open(any_parameters)
```

**code being tested**

```
txt = Resolv::DNS.open do |dns|
            records = dns.getresources(options[:cname_origin], Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME)
          end
          binding.pry
          return (txt.size > 0) ? (options[:cname_destination].downcase == txt.last.name.to_s.downcase) : false
```

**my test**

```
::Resolv::DNS.expects(:open).returns(dns = mock)
  dns.expects(:getresources)
     .with(subject.cname_origin(true), Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME)
     .returns([Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME.new(subject.cname_destination)])
     .once
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are testing that `Resolv::DNS` receives `open` returns your `mock` but 
since you seem to be trying to test that the `dns` mock is receiving messages you need to stub the method and provide it with the object to be yielded

Try this instead:

```
 dns = mock 
 dns.expects(:getresources)
   .with(subject.cname_origin(true), Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME)
   .once
 ::Resolv::DNS.stub :open, [Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME.new(subject.cname_destination)], dns do 
   # whatever code actually calls the "code being tested" 
 end 
 dns.verify
```

The second argument to stub is the stubbed return value and third argument to `stub` is what will be yielded to the block in place of the original yielded.

In RSpec the syntax is a bit simpler (and more semantic) such that:

```
 dns = double 
 allow(::Resolv::DNS).to receive(:open).and_yield(dns) 
 expect(:dns).to receive(:getresources).once
   .with(subject.cname_origin(true), Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME)
   .and_return([Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME.new(subject.cname_destination)])
  # whatever code actually calls the "code being tested"
```

Comment: This works fine. But I was actually able to get it working with a single line. `Resolv::DNS.any_instance.stubs(:getresources).returns([Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME.new(subject.cname_destination)])`

Comment: @AntarrByrd if that was the whole goal then `::Resolv::DNS.stub :open, [Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::CNAME.new(subject.cname_destination)]` should have satisfied that since the block has no purpose in that context. (e.g. you are not testing `get_resources` was called or the arguments it was called with)

Comment: You are right. I think I will go with your approach since it provides more coverage. The only problem is that I get `unexpected invocation: #<Mock:0x7f8f1a6b7550>.verify()` when calling `dns.verify`

Comment: @AntarrByrd I assumed `mock` was an instance of  `Minitest::Mock` e.g. `mock = Minitest::Mock.new` in which case `verify` is the method that literally verifies the expectation. If you are using a different library for mocks( I am now assuming you are using `mocha` to mock objects) in which case the verify is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can write more readable integration tests with DnsMock instead of stubbing/mocking parts of your code: https://github.com/mocktools/ruby-dns-mock